# What does compatible mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordered-fields

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) defines ordered fields in the following way:

> An ordered field is a field together with a total ordering of its
>   elements that is compatible with the field operations, i.e.:
>
> A field $(F, + ,\cdot)$ together with a total order $\le$ on $F$ is an
>   ordered field if the order satisfies the following properties:
>
> if $a\le b$ then $a+c \le b+c$
>
> if $0\le a$ and $0 \le b$ then $0 \le a\cdot b$

My question is what is the exactly definition of compatibility (if there is one)? In the multiplication case shouldn't we have if $a \le b$ then $a\cdot c \le b\cdot c$ following the sum one?

Thanks

Comment: There's no general definition of compatible, afaik. When the phrase is used in algebra, it is typically followed by a clarification on the manner in which the objects in question are compatible.

Answer (score 4):

The exact definition in this case is what you recalled.

No, you would not want that for the multiplication, as it is not what one wants or has in say the real numbers.  $3 \le 5$ yet $(-1)3 > (-1)5$. It would even lead to absurdity right away:
we have $-1 \le 1$. So $(-1)(-1) \le (-1)1$ and $1 \le -1$.

You could however rephrase the condition for multiplication that is given in the equivalent form that $a \le b$ implies $ca \le cb$ for $c \ge 0$.